# Log JSON parameter to Google Sheet cell, using Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, console, webhooks

I'm recieving webhooks that read like this:

```
{
  "base": "BTC",
  "pair": "BTCUSDT",
  "signal": "long",
}
```

I'm using the below to capture the webhook in code.gs (in a Google Sheet) :

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
  params = JSON.parse(params);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);
  sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
  
  var timestamp = new Date();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(timestamp);  //<--------------this works
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(params.pair;);   //<----------this doesn't work
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(params.signal);   //<---------this doesn't work
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(params); //<------------------this works
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
}
```

What happens is the timestamp logs correctly to the right cell, as do the params log as well, but I can't get "params.pair" and "params.signal" to print to the sheet. (See the arrows in the code above).

Note that it works properly in a test where I simply input the webhook text as a string and run the same function. But when done via a webhook it doesn't seem to work, nor can I log anything to the console to debug.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're stringifying and parsing out again, which results in a no-op. Read  the linked duplicate answer.

Comment: @TheMaster the linked comment doesn't directly answer my question. The solution tells me to re-parse as a new variable, and then call params["signal"] which doesn't work. I'm after an explicit answer to my question please.

Comment: That's not what the solution says. `var params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
  params = JSON.parse(params);` What do you think  is the type of `params` and `e.postData.contents`?

Comment: Can you give `e.postData.contents` as is without any transformation?

Comment: Remove `var params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
  params = JSON.parse(params);` and add `var params = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)`. If it doesn't work, [edit] your question to add your current code and explain why the linked answer isn't working.